# Printing parts of a dictionary by using a for loop Pandas Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, formatting

I am trying to read the `Accounts.csv` and then I am trying to format it so that the read csv is the format of the `dictionary` below. How would I be able to do that?

Accounts.csv file:

```
AccountName, APIkey, APIsecret
Account1,sdhsdhjsd,sadjkaskldjaskdadasdfvg
Account2,sdasdasdadc,sdasdasdassvsdvdsfdfsaf
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

data =pd.read_csv('Accounts.csv').to_dict('dict')
for clients_info in Accounts.values():
     print("Accountname:", clients_info['AccountName'], "APIkey:", clients_info['APIKey'], "APIsecret:", clients_info['APIsecret'])
```

Expected output:

```
Accountname: Acount1 APIkey: sdhsdhjsd APIsecret: sadjkaskldjaskdadasdfvg
Accountname: Acount2 APIkey: sdasdasdadc APIsecret: sdasdasdassvsdvdsfdfsaf
```

Actual output:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `df.to_dict` is what you're after.

you can specify what orientation you need, in this instance let us try `records`

```
dataframe_dict = df.to_dict(orient='records')

[{'AccountName': 'Account1',
  ' APIkey': 'sdhsdhjsd',
  ' APIsecret': 'sadjkaskldjaskdadasdfvg'},
 {'AccountName': 'Account2',
  ' APIkey': 'sdasdasdadc',
  ' APIsecret': 'sdasdasdassvsdvdsfdfsaf'}]
```

---

```
for item in dataframe_dict:
    print(item)

{'AccountName': 'Account1', ' APIkey': 'sdhsdhjsd', ' APIsecret': 'sadjkaskldjaskdadasdfvg'}
{'AccountName': 'Account2', ' APIkey': 'sdasdasdadc', ' APIsecret': 'sdasdasdassvsdvdsfdfsaf'}
```

or using the `AccountName` as your dictionary key.

```
dataframe_dict = df.set_index('AccountName').to_dict(orient='index')

dataframe_dict['Account2']['APIkey']

'sdasdasdadc'


dataframe_dict['Account2']['APIsecret']

'sdasdasdassvsdvdsfdfsaf'
```

Comment: I want to more so access the `AccountName` and `APIkey` and such. Like dataframe_dict['Accountname']

Comment: @tonyselcuk well you'll need to use a `unique key` to create your dictionary so you have a single dictionary object. Are the accounts unique?

Comment: So what I was going for was that it would iterate all the values of the dictionary with a for loop and get the corelating values for `AccountName, APIkey, APIsecret`. Just like how my print statement was formatted. Sorry for the confusion.